# Scope associated models by "created_at"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scope, model-associations

I have three models : User, Product and Ownership. An ownership has a `product_id:integer` and a `user_id:integer`. I want to scope my products by `created_at DESC`.

**app/models/product.rb**

```rb
        .
        .
        .
default_scope -> { order('products.created_at DESC') }
        .
        .
        .
```

But when I do `user.owned_products`, it's not ordered like `created_at DESC`. How can I do that ? Must I add a scope in my user model ?

Here is the relationship between my users and products :

**app/models/user.rb**

```rb
        .
        .
        .
has_many :ownerships
has_many :owned_products, through: :ownerships,
                          source: :product
        .
        .
        .
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set the order on a user's owned products, you can specify this in the association. For example:

```
has_many :owned_products, through: :ownerships,
                          source: :product,
                          order: "created_at DESC"
```

Comment: Thank you, it works ! But this method is deprecated, we must use something like `has_many :owned_products, -> { order "created_at DESC" }, through: :ownerships, source: :product`.